# how to get last inserted unique combined foreign keys of two other tables as single key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

Lets take three tables... **USER**, **PRODUCT**, **ORDERS.**

```
USER(user_id,name); 
PRODUCT(product_id,price);  
ORDERS(user_id,product_id,order_code,paid);
```

here we have user_id and product_id in ORDERS table as foreign key for USER and PRODUCT tables which together makes a unique index.

Oright..

Assume that there are data rows in user and product tables.
So, I'm inserting into ORDERS table

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS(user_id,product_id,paid) VALUES ('2','1','true');

SELECT @lid:= /* some function which can return last inserted combination of foreign keys as single identifier */;

UPDATE ORDERS SET order_code=concat(
    substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@lid)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
              substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
              substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1)
             )
     WHERE /*in here combined foreign key*/ = @lid;
```

I want to get the last inserted id (as in LAST_INSERT_ID) of two foreign keys as a single key which can be used to update the table.

Now, I know that I can accomplish this by introducing a primary key to ORDERS table which will solve the problem as such.
But, I don't want to do that.

I have also searched this type of questions but it didn't solve my problem.

Any help is appreciable. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this might work...
create a column with auto_increment named *inc* then

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS(user_id,product_id,paid) VALUES ('2','1','true');

SELECT @lid:= select max(inc) from ORDERS;

UPDATE ORDERS SET order_code=concat(
    substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@lid)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
              substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1),
              substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand(@seed:=round(rand(@seed)*4294967296))*36+1, 1)
             )
     WHERE inc = @lid;
```

your are done.

Answer (score 0):

based on the fields in your tables you cannot determine the last inserted rows definitely.

As you say either add in a primary key or alternatively as you dont want to do that you could add in a timestamp field which adds sysdate when data is inserted. However I think that if you can add a field, adding in a PK will make finding the last entry easier as you just look for the MAX PK to identify the most recent entry.

Comment: If I use timestamp but, is there any function so which will help me to find exactly that row in the query like kind of 'last_inserted_timestamp' or something like that. You know what I mean.

Comment: I want to store it in the variable @lid. I hope you understand.

Comment: Suggest that you either add an auto incrementing field into orders e.g ORDER_NUMBER, this will add one for every entry. Identifying the most recent entry is just a case of using MAX(ORDER_NUMBER) to get the most recent entry. This is a much more reliable way than using a timestamp/dates as you could have multiple entries on one date so therefore you need to compare the date and time. Whereas looking for a MAX value in ORDER_NUMBER would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an auto increment field in ORDERS. Then to return the most recent entry you would do:

```
     SELECT MAX(your auto incrementing field) from orders.
```